# How to better search using web api or angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I`m working on my project with asp.net web-api as back
and with angular 8 as front.

I want to make a little search engine ,let say i have a cars data and i want only the cars that have manual gear,
so for my question should I create a get method in the web-api side that will 
return a  IEnumerable of cars with manual gear, or better create a pipe 
in the angular side ? what is the common better way ?

Comment: I think you are confusing the server-side and client side together. Even when you use an angular pipe, you will at some point talk to your api if you want to search the database. So you will always need a web api endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to create a REST API to get car list with all possible filter e.g. page size, page number, search keyword, manual gear, car color, price range, etc as an optional parameter and call the WebAPI from angular when the filter is applied.

Comment: ok thanks will do, but for other question I need to create search by free text I can I do that ?

Comment: you need to add query parameter for search in your car listing API, which will give you feasibility to search on free text.

Comment: can you give me a example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The better pratice its use web-api for search thes informations and use angular in frontend for show the informations.

Comment: It's better to post this as comment. Try to gain more reputation by editing questions.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for help!